NPM package depends on another package from yarn workspace. Module declaration of dependency not found in consuming project
I am working on a monorepo using yarn workspaces. One of my packages is a react library that is published to NPM. It depends on a core package within the monorepo which is not published.
I have set up a project to reproduce the issue:
This is the repository -- test-monorepo
This is the package on the NPM registry -- jake-react-lib
The Issue:
When I install jake-react-lib in another project and hover my mouse over UserProvider I see:
const UserProvider: React.FC<any>

If you go to the source code in node modules/jake-react-lib/dist/provider/UserProvider.d.ts you can see that jake-core module is not found.
// in my node_modules of consuming project -- node_modules/dist/provider/UserProvider.d.ts
import { UserConfig, UserContext } from 'jake-core'; // Cannot find module 'jake-core' or its corresponding type declarations

When I build the library locally I can see the types correctly inferred and the path to the module is found.
// hover mouse over `UserProvider`
const UserProvider: React.FC<UserProviderProps>

// in my local project -- ./dist/provider/UserProvider.d.ts
import { UserConfig, UserContext } from 'jake-core'; // module is found, and types are recognized.

The functionality is there--i.e. the code works as expected. But I'm trying to figure out why the module declaration is not shipped to the project that consumes jake-react-lib

There's a lot that you haven't specified. What is your intended TS target which has implications for module and moduleResolution? If you want to use types from jake-core inside of jake-react-lib then you'll have to either publish those types, redefine them inside of jake-react-lib and publish them with that package, or change your overall architecture altogether to get what you want. Both of jake-core and jake-core-lib defines "type": "module" in their corresponding package.json, but you are not using the exports field which is not ideal for consumers.

Why not publish jake-core, or publish only the types of jake-core? Clearly define your requirements and that will help determine the best overall architecture to use. I would also be consistent and use ES modules while also defining an exports field in the package.json to better control exports. You're probably better off with a target of ESNext and module of NodeNext and moduleResolution of NodeNext. At the very least to get through this current impasse you will need to publish the types from jake-core or redefine them in jake-react-lib.

To get an idea of what I'm talking about, change the target for the consuming application to ESNext, for example, and you'll see another error about module resolution. Then set module and moduleResolution to NodeNext in the consuming project and you'll see an error about jake-react-lib not having an export named UserProvider.

I'm using a monorepo because I'm managing 3 frontend libraries (React, Angular, and Vue) that share the framework-agnostic functionality of a core package. I'm seeing--thanks to your advice--that exposing a jake-core type declaration to the end user of jake-react-lib is not possible without publishing the core package or redefining the type in the react package. Thank you for your advice on this issue, as well as the extra improvements to my project setup. @morganney

Monorepos are great, I use them all the time. How you want to define the interdependencies between the workspaces and what gets published is entirely dependent upon your preferences and the overall project requirements, as you’ve been discovering. Most of this is of course dependent upon how node_modules operate and their lookup algorithm.
